# Replacing the Glyphicons icons or Adding some new ones to it

Tags: css, wordpress

When I looked up the theme files , It has a folder Named **glyphicons** , in **/wp-content/plugins/nhpoptions/img/glyphicons** , This folder has png images naming glyphicons_000_glass.png and so on , upto glyphicons_349_readability.png , I thought it would be too simple and I just need to replace the images with my own so I renamed my image glyphicons_349_readability.png and replaced the old one but this did not solved it. Still the same icon is appearing . Please tell me what am I missing ,
 here is the screenshot of the dir

[image: Screenshot]

Test Site Link = http://test.yoapp.nl/
Theme = http://themeforest.net/item/couponer-coupons-discounts-wp-theme/8322172
*****UPDATE*****
There is a file named font-awesome.min.css in the theme , It has the icons added from font awesome , Now I figured out to add more icons from font awesome but still I am stuck on adding my own icons.

Comment: You would need to send a link to the site or the demo site where the problem is. Have you tried clear your cache? Looked at it in a different browser?

Comment: Test Site Link = http://test.yoapp.nl/ Theme = http://themeforest.net/item/couponer-coupons-discounts-wp-theme/8322172 . There is a file named font-awesome.min.css in the theme , It has the icons added from font awesome , Now I figured out to add more icons from font awesome but still I am stuck on adding my own icons.

Comment: Which glyphicon specifically. It is most likely they are embedded into the css

Comment: Yes they are being added from font awesome through a css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author(s) of the theme is using CSS to embed the icons using the font-family and content attributes in the style.css file. For example:

**style.css - line 713**

```
.filter-tabs ul.nav-tabs li.active:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #24b6ac;
    content: '\f0d7'; /* This refers to fa-caret-down */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -14px;
    left: 47%;
}
```

And

```
a.btn-top:before {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-size: 31px;
    content: "\f0da"; /* refers to fa-caret-right */
    position: absolute;
    left: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    top: 128px;
}
```

These can be found in your style.css file. There is 4 more instances which you can track down yourself I'm sure. This is done by setting the font-family attribute to `Font-Awesome` and setting the unicode for the `content` property. You can see a full list of the icons, including their class and unicode here: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/